# Django - pre-selected radio button from BooleanField

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have been able to get the `BooleanField` from my main `Feature` class to be rendered as a radiobutton for its form, but when viewed, the form doesn't have the corresponding value preselected. How do I get it to select the appropriate one, given a boolean value? Thanks

models.py:

```
class Feature(models.Model):
    for_biz = models.BooleanField()


class FeatureForm(ModelForm):
    choices = ( (1,'Business'), (0, 'Customers') )
    for_biz = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        coerce=lambda x: bool(int(x)),
        choices=choices,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Feature
        fields = (
            'for_biz',
        )
```

views.py:

```
def edit_feature(request, f_id):
    f = get_object_or_404(Feature, id=f_id)
    form = FeatureForm(instance=f)
    ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a `PositiveSmallIntegerField` with `choices`. `BooleanField` doesn't really buy you anything, and as you already saw it only gives you more trouble to deal with.

Comment: @katherine: Yeah, typing from memory.